# CAS being ignored by ASP.NET 2.0 application in IIS 7, not ignored in Visual Studio server

Tags: asp.net, cas

I've got an ASP.NET 2.0 application (references System.Web, etc., v. 2.0) using the .NET CAS client.  It works fine using the Web server built into Visual Studio, but when I deploy to IIS7, rather than using the CAS settings in Web.config to log in using my CAS url with the `service` query string parameter with the full URL (which happens during debugging), it uses `ReturnUrl` query string parameter as though it's doing regular old authentication.

I'm not sure where to begin.  I haven't had luck getting anything out of log4net.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had both a `<modules>` and an `<httpModules>` tag in my Web.config.  The former worked with the Visual Studio debugger, but the latter was required for IIS.  I have both and everything works.